# neo4j-backup missing on Ubuntu

Tags: neo4j, backup

Where can I find `neo4j-backup` tool on Ubuntu? I installed Neo4j using standard `apt-get` installation, however the script is nowhere to be found. From what I can see in `ps aux`, Neo4j is in version 2.1.5 (I couldn't see how to check the version in a simpler way either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The neo4j-backup tool is only available on the Enterprise version. I imagine you've probably installed the community version?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In case of Neo4j community edition the right way seems to be bringing the database offline and manually copying the `graph.db/` folder.

Comment: `neo4j-admin` should include warnings for commands that differ between the community and enterprise editions. I couldn't tell from the URL of the operations manual that I was looking at the enterprise manual (I use community edition for now): https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/perform-backup/